# Sweet alert problema en JSF

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsf, sweetalert

Estoy intentado integrar el plugin de sweet alert en un boto en JSF para que se vea una ventana de confirmación presentable, el problema es que al presionar el boto se abre el sweet alert pero igual ejecuta el action del cntrolador sin tener en cuenta la confirmación y refresca la pagina, es decir que el sweet alert si sale, pero refresca la pagina y por ende éste se cierra.

Éste el codigo que manejo en el javascipt

```
function dialog() {
            event.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "Your will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false},
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
```

Y éste es el codigo en la JSF page

```
<h:commandLink id="boton" onclick="return dialog()" action="#{productosController.refrescar()}">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>                         
                </h:commandLink>
```

Alguien que pueda brindarme su ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

Proba de la siguiente forma:
Cuando creas el swal podes poner botones que tengan un value, luego capturando ese value podes hacer un switch y realizar la opcion asociada al valor ej aceptar, cancelar.
Te dejo un ejemplo hecho en html por si te sirve de guia:

```html
<div id="uno">Prueba</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>
swal("Prueba SweetAlert", {
  buttons: {
aceptar: true,
cancelar: true
  },
})
.then((value) => {
  switch (value) {
 
case "cancelar":
   swal("SE CANCELA LA ACCION", "Cancelado", "error");
  break;
 
case "aceptar":
  $('#uno').html("TEXTO MODIFICADO")
  swal("SE ACEPTA LA ACCION", "Se cambio el texto del div a TEXTO MODIFICADO", "success");
  break;
  }
});
 </script>
```